# 2 CATransition, left and right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, catransition

I am trying to develop a simple CATransition that shows an UIView appearing from the left.

Here it is the code:

```
CATransition *transDerecha=[CATransition animation];
        [transDerecha setDuration:1];
        [transDerecha setStartProgress:0];
        [transDerecha setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
        [transDerecha setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
        [transDerecha setDelegate:self];
```

Ok, but to get the aspect that i am looking for, i have created a UIView (blue one on the video).

I think that in the following video, you can see better what i am trying to say.
http://screencast.com/t/JMQmxe7CGy

The problem comes when i try to make the same thing on the left. If i create another UIView to cover the left UIView, it will cover also the right cover.

So, is there any other CATransition type to make that? Or any solution?

ThankS!!!

Comment: When i refer to "in both sides" i mean, two differents CATransitions, to two differents UIViews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you need to dive down to CA to do this kind of thing. It can be done using UIView animations. Here http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial is a good tutorial on UIView animations.